# Missing Columns in Show Full Columns

Tags: amazon-rds

I have an Amazon RDS table where I seem to get different responses to the same query depending on how I submit the query.

When I type the following SQL into the interactive Query Editior I get the expected response:

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM XXX.FormTypeInfos LIKE '%'

(Response downloaded as CSV by clicking 'Export to csv' button in Query Editor):

```
Field,Type,Collation,Null,Key,Default,Extra,Privileges,Comment
CreatedAt,varchar(30),utf8mb4_unicode_ci,NO,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
ID,varchar(255),utf8mb4_unicode_ci,NO,PRI,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
ModifiedAt,varchar(30),utf8mb4_unicode_ci,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
AnnotationCount,int(11),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
DefaultTextColor,bigint(20),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
FormName,varchar(256),utf8mb4_unicode_ci,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
HasFormAdditions,int(11),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
ImportFileName,varchar(256),utf8mb4_unicode_ci,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
IsDeleted,int(11),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
IsDocumentControlled,int(11),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
IsForm,int(11),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
Owner,varchar(256),utf8mb4_unicode_ci,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
PortraitFontSize,int(11),NULL,YES,,NULL,,"select,insert,update,references",
```

But when I submit the exact same query through the serverless RDS interface, I capture the following json response. The json response is lacking two columns that are present in the csv response, AnnotationCount and IsDeleted.

```
{"columnMetadata":[{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Field","name":"COLUMN_NAME","nullable":0,"precision":64,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Type","name":"COLUMN_TYPE","nullable":0,"precision":65535,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":-1,"typeName":"MEDIUMTEXT"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Collation","name":"COLLATION_NAME","nullable":1,"precision":32,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Null","name":"IS_NULLABLE","nullable":0,"precision":3,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Key","name":"COLUMN_KEY","nullable":0,"precision":3,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Default","name":"COLUMN_DEFAULT","nullable":1,"precision":65535,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":-1,"typeName":"MEDIUMTEXT"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Extra","name":"EXTRA","nullable":0,"precision":30,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Privileges","name":"PRIVILEGES","nullable":0,"precision":80,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"},{"arrayBaseColumnType":0,"isAutoIncrement":false,"isCaseSensitive":false,"isCurrency":false,"isSigned":false,"label":"Comment","name":"COLUMN_COMMENT","nullable":0,"precision":1024,"scale":0,"schemaName":"","tableName":"COLUMNS","type":12,"typeName":"VARCHAR"}],"numberOfRecordsUpdated":0,"records":[[{"stringValue":"CreatedAt"},{"stringValue":"varchar(30)"},{"stringValue":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},{"stringValue":"NO"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"ID"},{"stringValue":"varchar(255)"},{"stringValue":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},{"stringValue":"NO"},{"stringValue":"PRI"},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"ModifiedAt"},{"stringValue":"varchar(30)"},{"stringValue":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"DefaultTextColor"},{"stringValue":"bigint(20)"},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"FormName"},{"stringValue":"varchar(256)"},{"stringValue":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"HasFormAdditions"},{"stringValue":"int(11)"},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"ImportFileName"},{"stringValue":"varchar(256)"},{"stringValue":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"IsDocumentControlled"},{"stringValue":"int(11)"},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"IsForm"},{"stringValue":"int(11)"},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"Owner"},{"stringValue":"varchar(256)"},{"stringValue":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}],[{"stringValue":"PortraitFontSize"},{"stringValue":"int(11)"},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":"YES"},{"stringValue":""},{"isNull":true},{"stringValue":""},{"stringValue":"select,insert,update,references"},{"stringValue":""}]]}
```

Both missing columns are integer columns, but not all integer columns are missing. I have another table that contains an IsDeleted column of type integer, but the IsDeleted column is included in both the csv and the json output in response to SHOW FULL COLUMNS for that table. Neither column name appears in the list of key words for MySQL, the RDBMS my table is emulating.

Is there a reason these columns are excluded from the json output?

Thanks